# Foundry: compile and test too slow

Tags: foundry

The problem is as the title. As we know, foundry is created by rust, it is very fast. But why my foundry is so slow?

my version: forge 0.2.0 (8307d6d 2023-04-19T16:44:52.696636400Z).cast 0.2.0 (8307d6d 2023-04-19T16:44:52.696636400Z). anvil 0.1.0 (8307d6d 2023-04-19T16:54:04.891176400Z). rust version: stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu (default)

here is the example, there is only one file in test folder: 900+ ms

```
PS E:\BlockChainPoC_github\BlockChainPoC> forge test
[⠔] Compiling...
No files changed, compilation skipped

Running 1 test for test/DFX.sol:ContractTest
[PASS] testExploit() (gas: 750212)
Test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; finished in 988.07ms
```

and another test costs 22 secounds!

```
PS E:\BlockChainPoC_github\BlockChainPoC> forge test
[⠒] Compiling...
[⠑] Installing solc version 0.6.12
[⠘] Successfully installed solc 0.6.12
[⠰] Installing solc version 0.6.9
[⠔] Successfully installed solc 0.6.9
[⠒] Installing solc version 0.5.16
[⠆] Successfully installed solc 0.5.16
[⠘] Installing solc version 0.6.6
[⠊] Successfully installed solc 0.6.6
No files changed, compilation skipped

Running 1 test for test/bamboo/poc.sol:ContractTest
[PASS] testExp() (gas: 131579220)
Test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; finished in 22.06s
```

Answer (score 1):

One of things you can do is follow best practices
https://book.getfoundry.sh/tutorials/best-practices

For example changing from

`import "src/MyContract.sol"`

to

`import {MyContract} from "src/MyContract.sol"`

Did reduce the compile time for me